# Integer parameter calls float overload and float parameter calls integer overload

Tags: c++, reference, overloading, rvalue-reference, lvalue-to-rvalue

Today I ran into roughly the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(float&& f) { std::cout << f << "f "; }
void f(int&& i) { std::cout << i << "i "; }

int main()
{
    int iv = 2; float fv = 1.0f;
    f(2);  f(1.0f);
    f(iv); f(fv);
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/roW7qd6fY)

The first two f-calls print `2i 1f`, as expected.

Now for the second line, I would have expected that it either doesn’t compile at all, since iv and fv are not temporaries (and thus can't bind to an r value reference), or that it creates a copy of the variable to pass to the function, and thus print `2i 1f` a second time.

However, somehow it prints `2f 1i`, which is just about the last thing I would have expected.

If you copy the code into cppinsights, it transforms the calls into

```
f(static_cast<float>(iv));
f(static_cast<int>(fv));
```

So it seemingly very intentionally casts the integer to a float, and the float to an integer, but I don't have any idea why it does that, and don't really know how to google that either. Why does this happen? What are the rules that lead to this result?

Comment: `f(iv);` cannot bind to `f(int&&)`, but it can bind to `f(float&&)` via a temporary.  And vice versa for `f(fv)`.

Comment: @Eljay Sometimes I just hate implicit conversion so much

Comment: @PepijnKramer • Sean Baxter's **New Circle** experiment allows you to opt-out of implicit conversion.

Comment: Yes or cpp2 (Herb Sutter). Like Bjarne says there is a better language hiding in C++ we just need to get it out. But thanks for the reference ;)

Comment: @Eljay if it can implicitly cast to float to bind to f(float&&) via a float temporary, why can't it implicitly cast to int to bind to f(int&&) via an int temporary? At best i'd  then expect an ambigous overload error or something along these lines

Comment: An `int` isn't *converted* to an `int`, it **is** an `int`.  So no conversion happens.  It's the conversion which makes a temporary.  You can force the temporary to be made by `f(iv+0)` (and I think `f(+iv)` might work as well).

Comment: Using j6t's technique to squelch conversions, and `f(+iv);` and `f(+fv);` to force temporaries, the code works for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior of the program can be understood from [reference-initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#ref-5.4).

From [dcl.init#ref-5.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#ref-5.4):

> [Example 6:
>
> ```
> double d2 = 1.0;
> double&& rrd2 = d2;                 // error: initializer is lvalue of related type
> int i3 = 2;
> double&& rrd3 = i3;                 // rrd3 refers to temporary with value 2.0
> ```
>
> -end example]

---

##### Case 1

Here we discuss why `void f(int&& i)` isn't viable for the call `f(iv)`.

The lvalue `iv` cannot be bind to the rvalue reference parameter `i` in `void f(int&& i)` for the call `f(iv)` and so the overload `f(int&&)` isn't **viable**. Basically, `int&& i = iv;` isn't allowed because `iv` is an **lvalue of related type.**

---

##### Case 2

Here we discuss why `void f(float&& i)` is viable for the call `f(iv)`.

For the call `f(iv)` the overload `void f(float&& f)` is viable because here first the initializer expression `iv` is [implicitly converted](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.ref#5.2.2.2) to a prvalue of the destination type(`float`) and then **temporary materialization** can happen such that the parameter `f` can be bound to that materialized temporary `2.0f`(which is an **xvalue**).

---

Similarly for the call `f(fv)`, the overload `void f(float&& i)` isn't viable because `fv` is an lvalue of related type. And for the call `f(fv)` the overload `void f(int&& i)` can be used because first the initializer is implicitly converted to a prvalue and then temporary materialization happens such that `i` can be bound to the materialized temporary `1`(of type `int`).

Comment: So if its the same type variable, they make the function not viable to protect you (because you clearly didnt want to put a variable into a function meant for temporaries), but when its not the same type, then suddenly its fine because you would have to create a temporary (result of a cast) anyway to call the function. One one hand I can kinda see the logic, but at the same time, it really makes me wish i learned java instead.

Comment: @user22879756 Basically, your program is same as `int iv = 2; int&& i = iv; /*won't work*/ float&& f = iv; //this will work`. So this doesn't have to do with functions in particular.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid implicit conversions being considered, rewrite your code like this using [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) syntax (because you used that in your [Compiler Explorer](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer) link).
At least the faulty code would not compile now.

By making explicit constraints, the types have to exactly match and no implicit conversion is considered. ([C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20) syntax would be a bit nicer.)

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/MexsGT55T

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename type_t>
auto f(type_t&& f) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<type_t, float>, void>
{
    std::cout << f << "f ";
}

template<typename type_t>
auto f(type_t&& f) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<type_t, int>, void>
{
    std::cout << f << "f ";
}

int main()
{
    int iv = 2;
    float fv = 1.0f;

    f(2);  f(1.0f);
    f(iv); f(fv); // <== Will no longer compile now
}
```

Comment: Slightly less ugly (but still ugly ;P): https://godbolt.org/z/Y33WP8ae5

Comment: Or C++20 : https://godbolt.org/z/z66EM7fM8

Comment: You can use `same_as` instead of `is_same` in C++20, e.g. `auto f(std::same_as<int> auto && f)`  :)

Comment: @alagner Thanks, I am still getting up to speed with C++20/concepts. Not half as familiar with them as with SFINAE ;)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the implicit conversions, provide a delete function template that is picked if the non-templated overloads do not fit exactly. That is, just add this overload:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&&) = delete;
```